# Call slick after click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I got a problem calling a slick after click event.

```
$('.gallery').slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    centerMode: false,
    variableWidth: true,
    arrows: true
});
```

This just works fine after page load, but the problem is with this code:

```
$('.slickit').on('click', function () {
    $('.gallery').slick({
        dots: false,
        infinite: false,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        centerMode: false,
        variableWidth: true,
        arrows: true
    });
});
```

I can't manage to call slick on click function.

The error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (module.js:4)
at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.js:5206)
at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.2.1.js:5014)
```

Comment: have you added jquery.min.js on top before slick.js?

Comment: Yes, jquery first, then slick and my js with code.

Answer (score 0):

the issue might be controller is not getting the slick.js liberary file just include the slick.js liberary file above the slick initialization and make sure that slick.js version be updated.